# simultaneous parameter and variance estimation in statistical inverse problem

Tags: inverse-problem, tikhonov-regularization

**Background:** I'm working on a geophysical inverse problem and interested in regularization parameter selection.
Just by way of explanation, we're trying to estimate the friction underneath a flowing glacier from measurements of the surface velocity and other parameters.
I'll write the log-friction as $\theta$ and the velocity $u$.
The two are connected by some physical model which can be expressed as $F(u, \theta) = 0$.
The loss function to be minimized is the misfit between $u$ and some observed values $u^o$ at a set of points $\{x_k\}$:

$$
\mathscr J(u) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_k\frac{|u(x_k) - u^o(x_k)|^2}{2\sigma_k^2}
$$

where there are $N$ measurement points.
At the same time, we have some prior information on the parameters that they're not super rough:

$$\mathscr R(\theta) = \frac{1}{2|\Omega|}\int_\Omega|\nabla\theta|^2dx$$

is added as a penalty.
(There are other choices but in any case it's always something like $\|D\theta\|^2$ for some linear operator $D$.)
The whole Lagrangian functional is then

$$\mathscr{L}(u, \theta, \lambda) = \mathscr{J}(u) + \alpha^2\mathscr{R}(\theta) + \langle F(u, \theta), \lambda\rangle$$

where I've introduced a Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ to enforce the physics and a regularization parameter $\alpha$.

**Where I'm at now:** If we know that the measurement errors are IID normal random variables, then the sum of squared errors should be a $\chi^2$ random variable.
The discrepancy principle tells us that we should select $\alpha$ so that the normalized sum of squared errors is about equal to 1.

**The problem:** The measurement error standard deviations $\sigma_k$ are formal error estimates that the experts in remote sensing and satellite measurement techniques come up with, and these experts often admonish me not to take them too seriously.
The "true" measurement errors that we should be using are really equal to $\rho \sigma_k$ for some unknown scaling parameter $\rho > 1$.
**Can we estimate $\rho$ at the same time as $\theta$?**

I have a vague recollection of reading in a book that we can pose this as minimizing $\mathscr{R}(\theta)$ subject to the equality constraint $F(u, \theta) = 0$ and the inequality constraint

$$\mathscr{J}(u) \ge \rho^2.$$

The (scalar) Lagrange multiplier that enforces this inequality constraint takes on the same role as $\alpha$ before.
But just from this recollection I don't remember how to determine both $\rho$ and $\alpha$ at the same time and it's not clear to me that this should even have a unique solution.
**Is there a procedure like what I've described for simultaneously estimating the variance and parameters, and if so what is it called and what is the canonical reference for it?**
I can't remember what book I saw this in and I couldn't find anything that quite covered it from searching google scholar.
[This paper](https://doi.org/10.1088/0266-5611/28/11/115016) came closest but the methods look very different from what I'm thinking of.
Almost everything I could find on Tikhonov regularization assumed that the variances in the model-data misfit are known exactly.

**Caveats:** The parameters $\theta$ live in a Sobolev space and the problem is discretized using the finite element method.
The usual arguments from regression theory about the number of degrees of freedom for the parameter space no longer make sense because this space is infinite-dimensional.